# debug.keystore no Mac para gerar hash

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, hash, sdk

Preciso gerar a hash do meu Mac para adicionar no Facebook e poder dar continuidade ao aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo, onde necessita o login. Já executei o comando em diversos lugares mas quando coloco no app dentro do "developers.facebook" e executo o meu aplicativo, retorna que a chave é inválida.

Uma coisa que notei é que em muitos post, falam pra executar no local onde encontra-se o "debug.keystore" (normalmente em users/.android).

No meu Mac não existe esse diretório e muito menos o debug.keystore. Estou utilizando o Android Studio.

Alguém sabe alguma outra forma válida?

Comment: Em geral, é você quem gera o `debug.keystore` e guarda em algum lugar. Essa é a mesma chave que usa para assinar seu apk, para enviar ao Google Play. A pasta `.android` fica na home do seu usuário (se for igual ao linux). No caso, quando você faz build do apk, tem que especificar dentro do seu `build.gradle` as configurações de *signin*, isso é, a chave, o alias e as senhas.

Comment: Vou tentar verificar pelo build.gradle porque o diretório .android não existe em lugar algum da minha máquina. Obrigado pela ajuda @Wakim

Comment: Mas se você não configurou nada de assinatura de apk, então não vai ter isso lá. A configuração é para assinar o apk dependendo do seu `build flavor` (release ou debug) durante o build. Recomendo dar uma olhada nesse link para ajudar a configurar isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle

Comment: Engraçado que tenho uma máquina com Windows e não precisei fazer nada disso. O diretório e os componentes foram gerados normalmente. Apenas no meu Mac me deparei com isso, mas vou ver com calma. Tks @Wakim

Comment: Mas como você gerou o apk assinado? Além de configurar no gradle, você pode usar o menu **Build -> Generate Signed APK...** e fornecer as informações pela interface gráfica.

Comment: Não gerei nenhum apk assinado. Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento e fazendo os apps apenas para testes. Não entendi muito bem o link, eu preciso jogar todo aquele conteúdo no build.gradle? @Wakim

Comment: Você precisa colocar sim, porque essa configuração vai ser usada pelo gradle para assinar o apk. Mas onde o facebook cobra o hash? Mesmo para desenvolvimento? Tem algum link?

Comment: Sim... Precisa gerar a chave com o hash do computador para permitir que o app compilado nele acesse as funcionalidades através do SDK do Facebook... Desde um simples login até mais elaborados.  No Windows eu tirei de letra, no Mac estou apanhando. @Wakim

Comment: Fiz todos os passos que estão no link, gerou a chave assinada, os apks corretamente, porém esse diretório .android com o debug.keystore não é gerado por nada. Será que tem outra coisa a fazer? @Wakim

Comment: Luiz, o diretório deveria ser criado (não sei quando, mas é criado por alguém: o sdk ou android-studio). Mas o **debug.keystore** é seu, que você gera usando usando suas credenciais. Dê uma olhada melhor nesse link: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

Comment: Eu segui exatamente esse tutorial... Não sei oq possa estar acontecendo... De qualquer forma, valeu! @Wakim

Answer (score 1):

O diretório `.Android` juntamente com o `debug.keystore` estavam ocultos no meu Mac.

Executei o comando `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true` no terminal e reiniciei o `Finder`.

Após isso, o diretório foi exibido e consegui realizar o que queria.